# What is the difference between RestartRequired and RestartNeeded in Get-WindowsOptionalFeature output?

Tags: powershell, dism

I run the following:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName TelnetClient | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

It produces the following output:

```
{
    "DisplayName":  "Telnet Client",
    "Description":  "Allows you to connect to other computers remotely.",
    "RestartRequired":  1,
    "CustomProperties":  [
                             {
                                 "Name":  "Description",
                                 "Value":  "Telnet Client uses the Telnet protocol to connect to a remote Telnet server and run applications on that server.",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent"
                             },
                             {
                                 "Name":  "DisplayName",
                                 "Value":  "Telnet Client",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent"
                             },
                             {
                                 "Name":  "Id",
                                 "Value":  "44",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent"
                             },
                             {
                                 "Name":  "Type",
                                 "Value":  "Feature",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent"
                             },
                             {
                                 "Name":  "UniqueName",
                                 "Value":  "Telnet-Client",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent"
                             },
                             {
                                 "Name":  "Major",
                                 "Value":  "10",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent\\Version"
                             },
                             {
                                 "Name":  "Minor",
                                 "Value":  "0",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent\\Version"
                             },
                             {
                                 "Name":  "Name",
                                 "Value":  "TelnetClient",
                                 "Path":  "ServerComponent\\Deploys\\Update"
                             }
                         ],
    "FeatureName":  "TelnetClient",
    "State":  0,
    "Path":  null,
    "Online":  true,
    "WinPath":  null,
    "SysDrivePath":  null,
    "RestartNeeded":  false,
    "LogPath":  "C:\\Windows\\Logs\\DISM\\dism.log",
    "ScratchDirectory":  null,
    "LogLevel":  2
}
```

My question is in particular about what is the difference between "RestartNeeded" and "RestartRequired"? They both appear to be about the same topic. What exactly is the difference between them?

`"RestartRequired"` is actually an enumeration (`Microsoft.Dism.Commands.RestartType`) with values:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| No | 0 |
| Possible | 1 |
| Required | 2 |

(It is a pity that I am still using PowerShell 5.1 which lacks the `-EnumsAsStrings` option to `ConvertTo-Json` which was added in PowerShell 6 and 7.)

Comment: Well, it would appear `RestartRequired` is more _granular_ (3 options) than `RestartNeeded` (2 options, true or false)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen On my machine, `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64" | ConvertTo-Json` returns `"RestartRequired":  2` (`2`=`Required`) but also `"RestartNeeded":  false`. That data point seems to contradict the theory that `RestartRequired` is simply a more granular version of `RestartNeeded`.

Comment: Actually, it is called [DismRestartType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism/dismrestarttype-enumeration)

Comment: @Theo That's what it is called in the C API. In the PowerShell API it is called `Microsoft.Dism.Commands.RestartType`. That is demonstrated by this: `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName TelnetClient | Select { $_.RestartRequired.GetType().FullName }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** On features like `TelnetClient` which return a `[Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AdvancedFeatureObject]`:

- `RestartRequired` denotes whether a restart could be required after installing or enabling the feature
- `RestartNeeded` is used to show whether a restart is currently pending for the feature.

**Long Version:** The `AdvancedFeatureObject` type never actually gets this value set though. Instead, the property is only used by `Microsoft.Dism.Commands.ImageObject` which is returned from `Enable/Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature`. For example:

```
# I already have it installed:
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 'TelnetClient' | fl FeatureName,State,Restart*

FeatureName      : TelnetClient
State            : Enabled
RestartNeeded    : False
RestartRequired  : Possible

# I remove it, and save the output:
$result = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 'TelnetClient'| 
    Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature

# Returns an ImageObject
($result|gm).TypeName
Microsoft.Dism.Commands.ImageObject

# RestartNeeded is set here
$result

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : True

# It does not get set on the main object though (only State=Disabled):

FeatureName     : TelnetClient
State           : Disabled
RestartRequired : Possible
RestartNeeded   : False
```

I think the `RestartNeeded` property is only present on the `AdvancedFeatureObject` due to some type inheritance, and is not actually a useful property.